# Contains em Java, como buscar um texto em um ArrayList?

Tags: java

Em C# existem o método `contains` do System.Linq que busca texto em um lista, fiz os testes em Java e não encontrei uma forma parecido mesmo sabendo que em Java 8 tem expressão, existe alguma forma de fazer isso com expressão no Java?

Exemplo:

```
ArrayList<String> strListas = new ArrayList<>();
strListas.add("Paulo");
strListas.add("Adriano");
strListas.add("Paula");

strListas.Contains("Pa");
```

Resultado:

```
Paulo e Paula
```

Comment: Acredito que isso é possivel somente com loop.

Comment: @diegofm tem como dar um exemplo, por favor, obrigada!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Paulo");
list.add("Adriano");
list.add("Paula");
    
List<String> resultado = list.stream()
                            .filter(s -> s.contains("Pa"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
resultado.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Saída:

> Paulo
>
> Paula

Comment: Gostei dessa, faz o papel esperado, só não consigo votar nela, parece que tem uma pontuação. Vou aguardar. Obrigada!

Comment: note que ao utilizar stream não é possível parar a execução no meio da lista se encontrou o objeto desejado e aumentar o desempenho, o stream vai percorrer a lista inteira e somente então vai retornar o valor, nesses casos específicos utilizar o for mesmo

Answer (score 10):

Acho que você vai ter que percorrer a lista e fazer um laço para procurar.

```
for (String valor: strListas){
 valor.contains('Pa')
}
```

Comment: Obrigada. é uma forma, que eu queria evitar, mas, é bem natural. Ainda não posso votar.

Answer (score 7):

Se precisar de uma procuca com case insensitive, use `Pattern`:

```
ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();

strList.add("Paula"); // será encontrado
strList.add("Paulo"); // será encontrado
strList.add("paula"); // será encontrado
strList.add("Pedro");
strList.add("Pedro pa"); // será encontrado

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Pa", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

for (String nome : strList) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(nome);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Nome encontrado: " + nome);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada, o que eu fiz teste e juntei a sua solução com a do Felipe, funcionou também.